# Wordpress - Random page banner image

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to get my home page to display a random banner every time the site is loaded.

I used the following code in my functions.php file -

```
add_filter('body_class','random_background_images');
function random_background_images($classes) {

    // Generate Random number from 1 to 10.  
    $background_class = 'background_' . rand(1,10);

    $classes[] = $background_class;

    return $classes;
}
```

and then this in my custom.css file -

```
body.background_1 {
   background-image: url("images/home-bg/website-background1.jpg");
}
body.background_2 {
   background-image: url("images/home-bg/website-background2.jpg");
}
body.background_3 {
   background-image: url("images/home-bg/website-background3.jpg");
}
```

it seems to work, but puts the image as a background image, not a banner. 
Can anyone please help me change this code so it will apply to the banner section?

(The current banner is set from the front end with an uploaded image in the 'home' page setup.

Website is - https://flowersforeveryone.feedmybeta.com/

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this would depend on the html for the banner. Assuming the banner has a class of `.page-banner`, you could change your CSS slightly thusly:

```
body.background_1 .page-banner {
   background-image: url("images/home-bg/website-background1.jpg");
}

body.background_2 .page-banner {
   background-image: url("images/home-bg/website-background2.jpg");
}

body.background_3 .page-banner {
   background-image: url("images/home-bg/website-background3.jpg");
}
```

In CSS, the selector that comes after a space is a child of the previous selector.